# IMAP session unexpectedly finishes

Tags: imap, yahoo-mail

I work with yahoo imap server. Everything works fine for some time, then several `LIST` queries return with error `imapclient got NO in response: Server returns NO for "A00393 LIST "" "*"": LIST Invalid credentials`, then "the last" `LIST` query return with error `imapclient general error: Fatal server ERROR after "A00394 LIST "" "*"": IMAP4rev1 Server logging out`. Then new imap session starts and everything works fine.

1. How can I get `Invalid credentials` error and in new session everything works fine with the same credentials?
2. Can this be problem from server side? How to validate this?

Comment: How long are you keep the session open?  Yahoo's authentication infrastructure is pretty opaque, and certainly is known to hiccup occasionally (eg, have brief outages).  As an email developer, I've found it's best to treat credential failures as a soft error for some time (~10 minutes) and retry. Only report the problem if it continues beyond that.

Comment: @Max, session has no timeout and reopened after close. The period of "Everything works fine for some time" before problems with `LIST` lasts for non-determined amount of time (from 10 to 40 minutes from what I saw from logs).

Comment: At least in the past, Yahoo did not really want people to hold connections open for more than one "download everything" cycle and would close the connection.  But, also, they occasionally just have authentication outages which you just have to take in stride and retry.

Comment: @Max, it would be okay, if connection was just closed, but problem is that I just get error response from server. It seems that I should, as you said, treat IMAP errors somehow.